# Data from local .mdf not showing in listView

Tags: c#, sql-server, database, listview

When I run my code,I get no errors and the code seems to run properly but the data from the database does not show up on my listView.

Here is my designer form code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Configuration;
using System.Data.SqlClient;

namespace Cookbook
{
    public partial class frmMain : Form
    {
        SqlConnection connection;
        string connectionString;

        public frmMain()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            connectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["Cookbook.Properties.Settings.CookbookConnectionString"].ConnectionString;
        }

        public void frmMain_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            PopulateRecipes();
        
        }

        public void PopulateRecipes()
        {
            using (connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
            using (SqlDataAdapter adapter = new SqlDataAdapter("SELECT * FROM Recipe", connection))
            {
                DataTable recipeTable = new DataTable();
                adapter.Fill(recipeTable);

                lstRecipes.DisplayMember = "Name";
                lstRecipes.ValueMember = "Id";
                lstRecipes.DataSource = recipeTable;
            }       
        }


        public void PopulateIngrediants()
        { 
            string query = "SELECT a.Name FROM Ingrediants a" +
            "INNER JOIN RecipeIngrediant b ON a.Id = b.IngrediantId" +
            "WHERE b.RecipeId = @RecipeId";

            using (connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
            using (SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(query, connection))
            using (SqlDataAdapter adapter = new SqlDataAdapter(query, connection))
            {
                command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@RecipeId", lstRecipes.SelectedValue);
                DataTable ingrediantsTable = new DataTable();
                adapter.Fill(ingrediantsTable);

                lstIngrediants.DisplayMember = "Name";
                lstIngrediants.ValueMember = "Id";
                lstIngrediants.DataSource = ingrediantsTable;
            }
        }

        public void lstRecipes_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            PopulateIngrediants();
        }

        private void lblRecipes_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        private void frmMain_Load_1(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }
    }
}
```

My app config:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
    <configSections>
    </configSections>
    <connectionStrings>
        <add name="Cookbook.Properties.Settings.CookbookConnectionString"
            connectionString="Data Source=(LocalDB)\MSSQLLocalDB;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\Cookbook.mdf;Integrated Security=True"
            providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
    </connectionStrings>
    <startup> 
        <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.5.2" />
    </startup>
</configuration>
```

This is the structure of my code and the views are blank when I run:
[image]

Note: I'm using Visual Studio Community 2015 update 3 and I'm new to VS and C#.

Comment: Let me know if more information is needed.

Answer (score 0):

You have multiples problems in your code.

- You forget to open connexion (and close its better)
- Your query have not space when you concat
- You forget to select id and you use id in valuemember
- You use command parameters and you use dataadapter without link

not sur my code rectified work but try this

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Configuration;
using System.Data.SqlClient;

namespace Cookbook
{
    public partial class frmMain : Form
    {
        SqlConnection connection;
        string connectionString;

        public frmMain()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            connectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["Cookbook.Properties.Settings.CookbookConnectionString"].ConnectionString;
        }

        public void frmMain_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            PopulateRecipes();

        }

        public void PopulateRecipes()
        {
            using (connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
            using (SqlDataAdapter adapter = new SqlDataAdapter("SELECT * FROM Recipe", connection))
                {
                connection.Open(); //Open connexion 
                DataSet ds = new DataSet();
                adapter.Fill(ds );

                lstRecipes.DisplayMember = "Name";
                lstRecipes.ValueMember = "Id";
                lstRecipes.DataSource = ds.Tables[0];
                connection.Close(); //close connexion
                }


        }


        public void PopulateIngrediants()
        { 
            //Donc forget space in your query when you concat string for create query, add column a.id if you want use in valuemember
            string query = "SELECT a.Name, a.Id FROM Ingrediants a " +
            "INNER JOIN RecipeIngrediant b ON a.Id = b.IngrediantId " +
            "WHERE b.RecipeId = @RecipeId";

            //Remove your command
            using (connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
            using (SqlDataAdapter adapter = new SqlDataAdapter(query, connection))
            {
                connection.Open() //open connexion
                adapter.SelectCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@RecipeId", lstRecipes.SelectedValue);//modify parameter of select command to dataadapter (verify selectvalue)
                DataSet ds = new DataSet();
                adapter.Fill(ds);

                lstIngrediants.DisplayMember = "Name";
                lstIngrediants.ValueMember = "Id";
                lstIngrediants.DataSource = ds.Tables[0];
                connection.Close() //close connexion
            }
        }

        public void lstRecipes_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            PopulateIngrediants();
        }

        private void lblRecipes_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        private void frmMain_Load_1(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: i have modify my code for use dataset instead datatable, try it

Comment: It's still the same :(

Comment: 1) Are you sur your connexion is good? 2) Have you datas in your database (smetime VS lose data in local DB)?  3) Recipe table have id and Name column? 4) Not data printed in listbox1 and 2? 5) Have you try to debug and found where is the problem?

Comment: verify if ds.Tables[0] has datas

Comment: I think the connection is good.
Yes i have a few datas in my database.
yes Recipe has id and Name.
I'm not so sure how to debug the problem.
How do i verify ds.Table[0]?

Comment: set breakpoint in code on this line " connection.Close(); //close connexion
" and put your mouse over ds.Table[0] and look into

Comment: Where can i find the "ds.Table[0]"? did you mean my database table? Sorry for the noob question.

Comment: Can I email you my full solution?

Comment: put your project on github and give his link here ;)